# Evaluating Word2Vec model by finding linear algebraic structure of words

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I have built Word2Vecmodel using gensim library in python.I want to evaluate my word embedding as follows

> If A is related to B and C is related to D, then A-C+B should be equal to D. For example, embedding vector arithmetic of "India"-"Rupee"+"Japan" should be equal to the embedding of "Yen".

I have used in built functions of gensim like predict_output_word,most_similar but couldn't get desired results.

```
new_model.predict_output_word(['india','rupee','japan'],topn=10)
new_model.most_similar(positive=['india', 'rupee'], negative=['japan'])
```

Kindly help me in evaluating my model as per the criteria above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should you the `most_similar()` method's `positive` and `negative` arguments in the same manner as the `accuracy()` method:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/718b1c6bd1a8a98625993d73b83d98baf385752d/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L697

Specifically, if you have a analogy of the form "A is to B as C is to [expected]", you should look at:

```
results = model.most_similar(positive=[word_b, word_c], negative=[word_a])
```

Or in your example:

```
results = model.most_similar(positive=['rupee', 'japan'], negative=['india'])
```